# Wi-Fi repeater which used to have Internet access lost this capability for no apparent reasons

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

[An image showing Repeater's info is also attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQt9S.png)

**Summary**:

I have a portable USB-powered Wi-Fi repeater which worked normally, i.e. had Internet access. Recently, I changed my ISP. Then, some time later, when first-time beginning to use the repeater with the new ISP's router, I found out that the repeater had no Internet access. I decided to reset the repeater, and completely re-did the set up process for the repeater. According to the set up wizard, the set up was successful, and the repeater should have had Internet access. Contrarily, however, it still had no Internet access.

**Additional Info**:

But, except for this no Internet access, I verified that the repeater functioned normally, as evident by its ability to 'Wi-Fi connect' to the ISP's router (the repeater automatically got an assigned IP in the same subnet as the ISP's router, and it even showed up as a connected device when I accessed the router's admin interface via a web browser). Moreover, another device could connect to the repeater's SSID (but, of course, such the device connected could not access the Internet).
I suspected that the new ISP's router (set up by its technicians) might be somehow connected with this problem of no Internet access provided by the repeater. My repeater used to work normally with the former ISP; and devices connected directly to the new ISP's router can access the Internet with no problems. Moreover, ISPs in my country are known to have their lent routers' capabilities and/or admin setting pages modified/removed by their OEM router suppliers, or themselves, with little or no disclosure.

On the other hand, just to make sure that it is not the fault of my repeater, I'd like someone to make comments about these settings:

**i)  Router IP = 192.168.1.1**. Router DHCP is configured to give IP range from 192.168.1.33 to 254. **SSID = My_Network**.

**ii)  Repeater's** (current) **SSID = My_Network_EXT**. When powered on. it would be DHCP-assigned an IP (in my case, it'll usually be 192.168.1.48), and connected to the ISP's router.

**Note 1.** The repeater's admin interface accessed at the said IP of 192.168.1.48 showed the current setting info as follows (*please see attached image*):
**WAN Status**:  Current mode = Repeater.  Internet = Connected.  WAN IP = 192.168.1.48.  Gateway IP = 192.168.1.1.  DNS1 = 192.168.1.1.  DNS2 = 0.0.0.0.    (***Remark***: For comparison; after factory reset, the following will be shown: Internet: Disconnect.  And WAN IP, Gateway IP, DNS1, DNS2 will all show: 0.0.0.0).
**LAN Status**:  LAN IP = 192.168.10.1.  Subnet Mask = 255.255.255.0
**Wi-Fi Status**:  Wi-Fi SSID = My_Network_EXT.    (***Remark***: For comparison, after factory reset, BlitzWolf_2.4G will be shown as Wi-Fi SSID if you access the repeater's admin interface at 192.168.10.1 via a web browser)

**Note 2.**  If you want to change any repeater's setting, you'll have to factory reset the repeater by long pressing on the reset button on the repeater's right side. After factory reset, you'll need to do the whole initial repeater's set up again by accessing the original repeater's IP of 192.168.10.1, in which case you'll be dictated by the repeater's admin interface to use a Wizard that offer very limited manual settings.

**iii)  When a device connects to the repeater (My_Network_EXT)**, it'll get an IP in the 192.168.10.x subnet, e.g. 192.168.10.100, as follows:
Device IP = 192.168.10.100.  DNS IP = 192.168.10.1 (Unencrypted)

When the repeater worked well with the former ISP, I did not take careful notes of all these settings mentioned above. But I firmly believe they all were exactly the same as they currently are in the case of the new ISP. The result is however, different. The repeater has now lost Internet access it used to have.

***Could someone kindly shed some light on this. please?***

Comment: You indicate the question is solved by [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). There is [no need for abusing the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/355310).

Comment: Blitzwolf NW-Net 4 is the model name. I used it to extend coverage area of the router. This is for basic Internet usage, and no need for file sharing nor device communications. The use of a USB repeater (powered by both an AC outlet or a power bank) offers tremendous flexibility.
Some product information
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOgSZZ7_frM

Comment: "Blitzwolf NW-Net 4 is the model name..." excellent info.  Please edit the question to include this info as opposed to placing in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue Solved** (posted by Original Poster):  **Part I**

Under the same settings set up via the repeater's Wizard, which had failed tens and tens of times after I changed the fiber-Internet ISP, the repeater finally has had Internet access now.

So as to exchange information with others, which might save time if they are facing similar situation, I'd describe my story in details.

In the case of the former fiber-Internet ISP, I also used this same Wizard for the 'initial' set up, which worked well. However, after changing the ISP, the repeater might need to be factory reset, and set up again so that the repeater would have reflected a new IP address in its DNS server setting (the former ISP's router IP was 192.168.0.1, while the new ISP's router uses 192.168.1.1). I didn't do a factory reset and a new set up for the repeater. And the no Internet access was probably because of a misconfigured DNS server; and after repeated failures to get Internet access, the repeater was in a state of severe 'hanging'. From my experience, when an IT device severely 'hangs', sometimes it will be very difficult to bring the device out of 'hanging'. In this case of the repeater, even after I did a factory reset, and re-did the 'initial' set up to make all the relevant settings correct, it still misbehaved. To make such device operate correctly again, you'll have to be patient and repeatedly attempt to find a way to induce the device to operate correctly at least once. after which the device may likely be gradually recovered from the state of severe hanging, and operate correctly from then on.

**Credit goes to dear Arbri**, whose advice has shed some valuable light on the issue:

What I actually did after posting the issue with superuser.

**1)** Try to determine how the repeater was designed to function by connecting an Android phone, and a Windows 11 tablet to the repeater SSID. The phone and the tablet were (DHCP) assigned an IP in the 192.168.10 subnet; being 192.168.10.100, and 192.168.10.101 respectively. Both the devices had no Internet access. However, I was able to make a Wi-Fi file transfer of file between the two devices, using the built-in Wi-Fi server capability of X-plore file manager app on the phone, and Firefox browser on the tablet.

**2)** Inspect the router settings (set up by the new ISP's technicians), trying to determine if any of the settings may interfere with the Repeater's Internet access. Under the heading of 'Firewall' > 'Device Access Control', I found this:

**Device Access Control**.  On this page, you can enable or disable permissions to access the device.
**ServiceName: HTTP**, which is followed by 3 tick boxes namely: **LAN**, **WAN**, and **Wi-Fi**. I saw that while the LAN tick box and the Wi-Fi tick box were ticked, the WAN tick box was left blank.

I was suspicious about the heading 'Device Access Control' and the logic behind such setting which had only the WAN tick box unchecked. **I thus also ticked the WAN tick box** (after all, if there later is a problem, I could just uncheck it), and rebooted the router.

**3)** Finally, I tried to follow **dear Arbri's advice**, step by step, on the Windows tablet. I just changed the Wi-Fi adapter's Network DNS settings from Automatic (DHCP) to Manual, and set IPv4 preferred DNS to 192.168.1.1.

I used Firefox to go to Google.com. To my surprise, it was successful. I then tried to use Firefox to start playing a YouTube video. After a while of what looked like Video buffering, the familiar fan-like Wi-Fi signal strength icon on the Taskbar turned to the 'globe' icon, which Windows used to indicate no Internet access. I refreshed the YouTube video page a few times, still the global icon didn't change to Wi-Fi signal strength icon.

I then switched Network DNS settings of the Wi-Fi adapter back to default, Automatic (DHCP), and tried to access little bandwidth-demanding websites such as Google.com, superuser.com, and was successful. I then tried to play a Youtube video. After some time of video buffering, the video started and played successfully. The fan-like Wi-Fi signal strength on the Taskbar stayed still, and didn't change to the 'globe' icon

**To be continued in Part II**

Comment: Yes, I had reset the repeater around 10 times. After each reset, a re-'set up' had to be done, and it had to be done using the Wizard. After 1st reset and re-'set up', still no Internet for my Windows tablet. I then disconnected the tablet from the repeater; reconnected it back, and checked for Internet, still no Internet. This procedure was repeated several times; with every time being no Internet. After an intermission of a few hours, the 2nd reset and re-'set up' began, and the mentioned whole procedure was repeated. Thus some 10 resets; and 50 connected, reconnected actually occurred

Comment: I understand.  Troubleshooting can be tricky and sometimes one can get in loops.  There are also multiple factors going on that you are not actively monitoring because you don't have the experience and/or the sw/hw.  You started confused, your question and answers are very confusing.  If you are intrerested I can work with you to improve your question and your answer so that it gets upvoted, not down, and it also offers value to the next person that comes along.  You are dealing with DHCP, routing, subnets, dual band WIFI dual, repeating, NAT etc. etc.

Answer (score -1):

**Issue Solved** (posted by Original Poster):  **Part II**

**Summary**: The Repeater is designed to work in such a way that: (just use the repeater's Wizard, and there's no need to alter anything)

**a)** it would receive an DHCP assigned and connected to a router (SSID of which is, say, My_network) in the same subnet as the router. In my case, the router's IP = 192.168.1.1; and the Repeater was assigned an IP of 192.168.1.48. (In other cases where the router,s IP = 192.168.0.1, the Repeater's IP would also be in the 192.168.0 subnet (e.g. 192.168.0.48)

**b)** When the Repeater DHCP-assign IPs to a device connected to it (SSID = My_network_EXT), the Repeater would assign an IP in the 192.168.10 subnet (which is a different subnet than that of the router), beginning from 192.168.10.100 and so on.

**c)** All devices whether connected to the router will have Internet access. But devices cannot communicate across each subnet. Thus if you want file sharing between a device X1 connected to the router, and device X2 connected to the repeater; you would have to connect them to the same subnet, which means switching device X1 to also connect to the repeater.

**PS: Small IT tidbits**, just to give credit where credit's due:

Below are issues causing difficulties and unnecessary wasting of time in my attempt to diagnose the problem. To err is human, but some of these errors are simply too much to ignore.

**i)** On Windows 11 tablet, the up-to-date Firefox v. 108.0.2 (64-bit) could not the repeater admin interface properly. It could connect to 192.168.1.48 (the repeater's IP), but presented only blank white page with absolutely no error such as 'We couldn't reach this website') It seemed that Firefox just couldn't render the 'log in' page. On the other hand, Firefox for Android v. 108.1.1 (installed on Windows 11 using Windows Subsystem for Android modified to be able to install apps from Google Play Store) was able to access 192.168.1.48 log in page of the repeater, and properly log in to see all the repeater's settings.

**My complaint**: How come the desktop Firefox, a native Windows application failed miserably, while Firefox for Android, running in a more-or-less emulator environment, the so-called Windows 11 Virtual Machine Platform, worked perfectly (albeit at a little slow pace). However, please see ii) below.

**ii)** When you input 192.168.1.48 in the URL bar of the Firefox for Android mentioned above and hit the 'Enter' button, the browser would automatically prefix this with https://, which would still make it unable to reach the log in page of the repeater. Only after deleting the 's' in https, making it http://192.168.1.48, would you then be able to access the log in page, and make a log in.

**My complaint**: In the Firefox for Android settings, the default setting of 'HTTPS-Only Mode' is 'Off'. How come 192.168.1.48 was automatically prefixed by https:\, and was not accessible until the user manually changed it to HTTP://

**iii)** This issue is particularly very annoying. My router broadcasts 2 SSID's of My_Network (for 2.4 GHz), and My_Network_5G (for 5 GHz). The  Windows Tablet Wi-Fi adapter is set to connect automatically to both these SSID's. But whenever I connected to the repeater's SSID of My_Network_EXT for a minute or so, it would secretly disconnect (possibly by reason of no Internet access, and automatically connect to either My_Network_5G or My_Network; depending on which one of these 2 SSIDs had been previously connected to. This happened even when the repeater was broadcasting a very strong unobstructed 2.4 GHz signal (it was about 30 centimeters from the tablet, whereas the router was broadcasting rather weak 2.4 GHZ and 5 GHz signals (the router was some 15 meters away and one floor below, with a fair amount is concrete obstruction). Since at the Tablet's position, the Wi-Fi adapter still had very usable Internet access from both the 5 GHz and 2.4 GHz radios provided by the router, this sometimes made me mistakenly thought that the repeater had Internet access (not knowing that Internet access didn't come from the repeater, but from the tablet's Wi-Fi adapter secretly switch to connect to the router.To stay connected with the repeater's SSID so as to conduct Wi-Fi file sharing between the Android phone and the Windows tablet mentioned above, I had to 'forget' both SSIDs of the router so as to have the 'connect automatically' feature disabled.

**My complaint**: I don't know whether the OS or the maker of the Wi-Fi adapter / driver is to be blamed of this annoying issue. Who do you think you are? Made some programming codes to switch from a connected Wi-Fi network with very strong signal to another network with a much weaker signal, for a mere reason of Internet access?, without the user's consent or at least an explicit warning. What about if the user has no need for Internet access at the moment, and just need file sharing or other forms of communications between devices. In my personal opinion (I had a university degree in Engineering), this issue reflects somewhat non-'engineering-minded' and disrespectful behavior of the people responsible for this. I wasted considerably unnecessary amount of time because of this.

**Best regards to everyone**.

Comment: There are many errors and much confusion routed in a lack of knowledge of networking &  WIFI.  This answer (question?) doesn't help it is simply confusing and error-filled.  The root of your problem is using a USB repeater (no use-case presented) that performs DHCP which should be handled by the LAN router if you are on your local network.    I suspect the device is intended for creating a small subnet to connect devices when you are a guest on a private network (coffeee shop, remote site, etc.).  Why do you need a USB repeater in range of the original wifi with existing LAN access?

Comment: **There are many errors and much confusion routed in a lack of knowledge of networking & WIFI**.
For the benefit of the readers, please point out the numerous errors you found.
**This answer (question?) doesn't help it is simply confusing and error-filled**. 
My English proficiency and explanation skills may not be good enough. But as already said, you're more than welcome to point out such errors.

Comment: **The root of your problem is using a USB repeater (no use-case presented) that performs DHCP which should be handled by the LAN router if you are on your local network**.
I ask for help to recover the repeater, which used to work properly for my purpose. So use-case is irrelevant. The repeater used to provide Internet access acceptably and reliably for some 15 months. Then it misbehaved. Several resets and re-'set up' simply did not work. (If you want to know the use-case, simply ask. Don't just blame me, based on 'no use-case presented'

Comment: **DHCP should be handled by the LAN router if you are on your local network**. For sure, the Blitzwolf is designed to DHCP-assign IPs in the range of 192.168.10.100; 192.168.10.101, ... and so on to connected  is devices. There's no way to change this. You should have waited until you know the actual situation before offering comments, let alone critizing the person posting the question. (Note: Another USB repeater, the Xiaomi Mi Wi-Fi Repeater ii should work similarly: https://mielygraphy.com/blog/reviews/xiaomi-mi-wifi-repeater-2-quick-review-and-set-up/ )

Comment: **I suspect the device is intended for creating a small subnet to connect devices when you are a guest on a private network (coffeee shop, remote site, etc.)**. 
Quite like that. As far as I know, in such Guest network, devices might not be able to communicate with one another, but devices in the Blitzwolf network can. I'd already mentioned about Wi-Fi file transfer in my 1st answer. **IMHO**, the Blitzwolf is designed to work as described in 'Making the most of an ISP-provided gateway: The Double NAT approach' at the bottom part of this page: https://dongknows.com/double-nat-vs-single-nat

Comment: **Why do you need a USB repeater in range of the original wifi with existing LAN access?**
No existing LAN access, and no less than 10 metros from an electrical outlet. As for use cases for a USB repeater, you may refer to: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Xiaomi-Mi-WiFi-Repeater-Amplifier/product-reviews/B00U0WGCQY

Comment: **Dear Blind Spots** I appreciate your respond. I think I understand you. And as I already said, please feel free to criticize and point out any errors for the benefit of the readers, whether in this post, or future posts. **Best regards**

Comment: I created a chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142125/wi-fi-repeater-used-to-have-internet-access-lost-capability for us to discuss this further as we are not using the commenting appropriately.  There we can have a discussion.  I appreciate the time and effort you are putting into this.

Comment: Hi Blind Spots.

Comment: Hi Blind Spots. I just logged in the chat room and couldn't chat because of 'You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq.' What further discussion you want to have? If it's about what you had done to me, I already said that I understood your explanation. It's OK now.